# Type error when trying to sort a list from a file

Tags: python, list, file, sorting, count

In Python, I am trying to return:

- a sorted list of unique words
- the count of the number of occurrences within a file

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.

My code is the following:

```
def countWords(ifile):
    lst1=[]
    infile=open(ifile,'r')
    lines=(inifle.read()).lower()
    for element in lines.split():
        lines.replace(',',' ')
        sct=lines.count(element)
        lst1.append(element)
        lst1.append(sct)
    return lst1.sort()
    infile.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong: you are trying to sort a list containing both strings and numbers. What should be considered greater `9` or `'dog'`?

Comment: 'dog' wold be considered greater

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to return a sorted list of unique words and the count of
>   the number of occurrences within a file.

I'd recommend using the `collections.Counter` data structure - its primary purpose is to count things.

```
from collections import Counter

def countWords(ifile):
    c = Counter()
    with open(ifile) as f:
        for line in f:
            c.update(line.strip().split())

    return c.most_common()
```

`most_common` returns word occurrences in descending order or frequency. Further sorting isn't required.

---

If your file is small enough, you could condense your function a bit:

```
def countWords(ifile):
    with open(ifile) as f:
        c  = Counter(f.read().replace('\n', ' ').split())
    return c.most_common()
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is not fine , the problem is in sorting.
You are getting this error as you are trying to sort 'str' and 'int'.
The script works fine if you don't try to sort it and also on another note you should close the file before returning the list.

Comment: The problem is I have to sort the two within a list. The word has to come first and then the number of its occurrences.

Comment: Is it compulsory to do it using a list ? You can use a dictionary for it that would suit your purpose more efficiently as 'words' can be used as keys and the counts as 'values'